# Listing all OU's in LDAP with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to list all Organizational Units (OU) from my LDAP directory. I am using the "devise_ldap_authenticatable" gem to authenticate my users. The LDAP sign in works fine. I am trying to get all the OU's now.

I'm new to LDAP, please let me know if my search query is wrong here.

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = "192.168.0.100"
ldap.port = 389
ldap.auth "cn=admin,dc=company,dc=com", "password"

treebase = "dc=company,dc=com"
filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "objectClass=organizationalUnit","company.com" )
attrs = ["*"]

ldap.search( :base => treebase, :filter => filter, :attributes => attrs, :return_result => false ) do |entry|
  puts entry
end
```

When I ran this, I got nothing returned. I have two OU's in my LDAP, DevOps and Development. There are 5 test users in each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it got me what I wanted and I'm happy with that.

I just removed the filter and retrieved the ou from the entry directly.

```
ldap.search( :base => treebase, :attributes => attrs, :return_result => false ) do |entry|
  puts entry["ou"]
end
```